# Syntax Error in If-Else Statement in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why is there a syntax error in this code on line 5?

```
n=int(input("Enter n:"))
if 1<x and 5>=x:
    if n%2==0:
        print("Wierd")
        else:
            print("Not Wierd")
            elif 5<n and 20=<n:
                if n%2==0:
                    print("Not Wierd")
                    else:
                        print("Wierd")
                        elif n>20:
                            if n%2==0:
                                print("Wierd")
                                else:
                                    print("Not Wierd")
```

Comment: Sometimes running a code checker like http://pep8online.com can help run down they syntax errors.

Answer (score 2):

The `else` and `elif` should not be indented that much. They should be on the same indentation-level of the `if` they match:

```
n=int(input("Enter n:"))
if 1<x and 5>=x:
    if n%2==0:
        print("Wierd")
    else:
        print("Not Wierd")
elif 5<n and 20=<n:
    if n%2==0:
        print("Not Wierd")
    else:
        print("Wierd")
elif n>20:
    if n%2==0:
        print("Wierd")
    else:
        print("Not Wierd")
```

Answer (score 0):

On the line no. 5 you have extra indented else. there is another issue on line 7 `elif` must have `if` before and it can't be written after `else`